# determining amount of CPU cache memory for a machine

Tags: windows, windows-xp, diagnostic

How can we find the amount of CPU cache memory a given machine has.

Assume Windows XP and a Intel Core Duo processor..

Comment: Are you talking about CPU cache? Which one (L1, L2, etc)? Do you need to get these values programatically (ie: through the Windows API)?

Comment: Unless you need to do this programmatically, this question is better asked on SuperUser.

Comment: yes CPU Cache.??

Comment: i dont need it through programmatically..!!
just need to find out- how much is the CPU cache for my system-JUST TO VIEW..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cpu-z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to find all the relevant information about your processor's cache. Look for the "Cache" section in the Cpu-z's main tab.

Comment: Where to download this from..?/

Comment: you can click on the link in Mikael's answer.

Comment: yup its nice,,!! ThanX bro..!!

Comment: Is there any other way to get this INFO..?? by using only WINDOWS XP OS ..?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed [Windows Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=50633A1F-A665-425D-923C-1A269F8AC084&displaylang=en) you can use the command: get-WMIObject Win32_Processor